# PostGIS raster to UTFGrid

Tags: postgis, raster, javascript, utfgrid

I am trying to create a UTFgrid JSON with a Raster in PostGIS. The goal is to provide weather data for web maps.

I found some libraries:

https://github.com/Ecotrust/create-utfgrids

https://github.com/springmeyer/utfgrid-example-writers

Is there one way to create the UTGrid from PostGIS using Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once wrote a UTFgrid function for PostGIS to be used with OSM data.

It's not particularly what you're looking for, but it might give you a start.

I don't know how it would work with raster though.

https://github.com/jimmyrocks/places-api/blob/7f048c2addebd9772e4718a4f0df4e44e981d0a3/scripts/sql_scripts/pgs/func_o2p.sql#L338-407